# I cannot run the program directly in VSCode but can run it using the terminal in VScode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

#### Environment Data

Windows 11
python 3.11.4
VS Code

---

#### Program Information

Here is some basic information about my program:
This program`s path: d:\Learning\Programming\python_work\File_Reader\file_reader.py

```py
file_path = 'File\\pi_digits.txt'
with open(file_path) as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read()
    print(contents)
#This program try to open the file:d:\Learning\Programming\python_work\File_Reader\File\pi_digits.txt
#and print the numbers stored in this file
```

So both **file_reader.py** and the folder **File** are in the folder **File_Reader**.
**pi_digits.txt** is in the folder **File**.
I want to use relative path to tell my program where **pi_digits.txt** is.
I run the code two times and I think at least my code is correct.

---

#### First Try

I run it in the terminal in VS Code

```
PS D:\Learning\Programming\python_work\File_Reader> python file_reader.py
```

And the result is exactly what I want

```
3.1415926535
  8979323846
  2643383279
```

---

#### Second Try

I run it using the **Run Code** button(Crtl+Alt+N)
But it seems that it fails to find where **pi_digits.txt** is.

```
[Running] python -u "d:\Learning\Programming\python_work\File_Reader\file_reader.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Learning\Programming\python_work\File_Reader\file_reader.py", line 2, in <module>
    with open(file_path) as file_object:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'File\\pi_digits.txt'

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.097 seconds
```

---

### The Last Try

I rewrite the program using the absolute path

```py
file_path = 'd:\\Learning\\Programming\\python_work\\File_Reader\\File\\pi_digits.txt'
with open(file_path) as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read()
    print(contents)
```

Both methods above work well

---

I cannot figure out why when I use relative path, the program doesn`t work in my *Second Try*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify a relative path, it matters which directory you are in when running `python file_reader.py`.

1. When you use Visual Studio, it will automatically load a shell in the project's base directory. That project directory also contains the file `py_digits.txt`, so everything works fine.
2. When you use any other terminal, it will by default load a shell in your user's home directory. And that home directory does not contain a file `py_digits.txt`, so it cannot be found.

When you specify an absolute path, it does not matter which directory you are in when running `python file_reader.py`. The file can always be found.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned by jraufeisen, this is to do with the different paths from `vscode` and the `terminal`.

I therefore tend to do something like this to have general code, but an unambiguous path.

```py
import os

current_file = os.path.abspath(__file__)
print(current_file)
```